# Always were or were always?

Tags: subjunctives, adverb-placement

> If I **always were** there, I would see everything.
>
> If I **were always** there, I would see everything.

What difference does the position of "always" make for this kind of sentence?

Comment: The position doesn't matter because "always" does not make any sense in this sentence.

Comment: I am looking at your edited version, and it makes more sense than the original. The position of "always" does not change the meaning, but the first sentence is not idiomatic. Even before I noticed your user name and your association with the Русский язык community, my first thought was, That sounds like Russian. (I live in Kazakhstan.) The second sentence sounds natural.

Comment: Heh heh. "Sometimes you all go away. But I'm always right here."

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, the adverb meaning frequency must be positioned either in front of general verbs or following be-verbs (or modals).
So, the second one sounds more reasonable to me.